# generate web based GUI to drag and drop components and connect them

Tags: javascript, user-interface, drag-and-drop

[image]We are trying to convert a desktop application into a web-based application. We need to create a GUI in which we can drag and drop components from the left side menu bar and connect them. Above sample output from the desktop application to show what kind of GUI's we are looking at. All these connected components will create a workflow. In these workflows we can connect terminals of few components to other components(not every terminal can be connected to every other terminal).

I am new to developing GUI for web based applications. We are planning to use javascript to develop this GUI. From Google I came across the library "wireit".

Can someone throw light on which libraries in javascript can be used to achive this. Any other web based architecture/languages which will help us in achieving this. Your replies 
will greatly help me in moving correct direction.

Comment: anyone had experience on using wireit library. Can I achieve the kind of workflows I am tlaking about using wireit??

Comment: Hi Hari, just wanted to know how did you achieve this requirement. Today I also need to create the exact same thing. Any pointers would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery UI has a good Draggable API: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: thank you for your response.
I am not sure whether I can generate the complete workflow GUI using jQuery UI.